# jquery - after clicking too fast animation get buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/81/)

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
      $('.wrapper').toggleClass('menu-open');

})
```

I want to have overlay when menu is open . so far so good .

but when i click too fast , overlay and menu aren't match .

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` events available in bootstrap framework like so:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.wrapper').addClass('menu-open');
});
$('.navbar-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('menu-open');
});
```

[Here is your **updated** JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/82/)

Answer (score -1):

Try Changing position property to absolute for navbar-collapse class

.navbar-collapse
{

```
z-index:2000;
position:absolute;
```

}